# What does "Just expected a gold star for doing your job" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am watching Younger, an American drama. The following exchange occurs in Season 1, episode 1, 16:10:

> A :Jane Austen has over 1,000 followers. How cool is that?
>
> B :Am I supposed to congratulate you?
>
> A: No, I just thought...
>
> B: **Just expected a gold star for doing your job.** That's the problem with your generation.

What does "Just expected a gold star for doing your job" mean?

Answer (score 5):

"Just expected a gold star for doing your job" is an accusation that a person has an exaggerated sense of entitlement. The accused expected special recognition (a gold star) for merely doing something required (his or her job).

Comment: Possible origin: self-adhesive gold(colored)-foil stars affixed to elementary school students'  accepted homework.